# How to convert SAP B1 Datatable to System.Data.Datatble using XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, datatable, sapb1

I am trying to convert SAP B1 Datatable to System.Data.Datatable using XML.

I tried to convert it manually using row by row but it takes too much time as data is very large.

Then I am trying to get XML from **SAP B1 datatable** using **DataTable.SerializeAsXML** method of the SAP datatable and then loading **System.Data.Datatable** using **dt.ReadXml** method but it is giving error.

I have read on another forum that XML of **SAP B1 Datatable** and **System.Data.Datatable** is different and need to transform using XSLT.

Can you please suggest any method and tools so that I can generate XSLT file for conversion of SAP B1 Datatable XML to System.Data.Datatable XML

Awaiting for your reply.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I did some reading and it looks like the SAP uses an ODBC connection to the database and uses the standard db.context methods in VS to extract data.  I'm not sure why you need xml unless the data was stored in the database in xml format.  The db.context consists of the database tables as list of classes.  So if you have a table in the database table Name with columns First and Last you would have List<db.context.Name> as the rows of the table.  So extraction would be var results = db.context.Name.Select(x => new { First = x.First, Last = x.Last}).ToList();

Comment: By "SAP B1 datatable" do you mean a DI-API recordset object?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a method which will take a SAP DataTable (as xml) and write it to a `System.Data.DataTable`.

I don't recall whether it gives the correct datatypes, or whether everything just comes out as a string.

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/elvishfiend/c67a2ceba57731c1fbe7b687e3dc9c49).

```
public DataTable SapDataTableToDotNetDataTable(string pathToXmlFile)
{
  var DT = new DataTable();

  var XMLstream = new System.IO.FileStream(pathToXmlFile, FileMode.Open);

  var XDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XMLstream);

  var Columns = XDoc.Element("DataTable").Element("Columns").Elements("Column");

  foreach (var Column in Columns)
  {
    DT.Columns.Add(Column.Attribute("Uid").Value);
  }

  var Rows = XDoc.Element("DataTable").Element("Rows").Elements("Row");

  var Names = new List<string>();
  foreach (var Row in Rows)
  {
    var DTRow = DT.NewRow();

    var Cells = Row.Element("Cells").Elements("Cell");
    foreach (var Cell in Cells)
    {
      var ColName = Cell.Element("ColumnUid").Value;
      var ColValue = Cell.Element("Value").Value;
      DTRow[ColName] = ColValue;
    }

    DT.Rows.Add(DTRow);
  }

  return DT;
}
```